# Apache Impala metadata - saparate from Hive or is it the same?

Tags: hadoop, metadata, impala

Pretty new to Hadoop ecosystem services here, starting to learn stuff bit by bit.

I tried to find out about Apache Impala and its metadata store. [The documentation](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/impala-3.3.pdf) says there's a daemon specifically for it and how it's gathered for each table. Other sources say that Hive metadata store is in fact also the Impala metadata store.
I can't find a single source for best practices or any type of user guide type document for handling metadata in Impala, is it because the metadata store is in fact the Hive store?

Just generally confused by the lack of information out there.

Comment: Hive and Impala metastore are same. This is impala/hive internal database stored in any relatational DB. Why you need to know it ? its internal so its kept hidden from outside. Not sure if you can access it though.

Comment: @KoushikRoy metadata stores are starting to be used for data governance, a very important issue since GDPR started becoming a thing.